# How to use xpath to locate an acronym in parenthesis in a title element? For example (ANT)

Tags: text, xpath, special-characters

In this xml example:

```
<concept><title>Another Neat Tool(ANT)</title></concept>
```

The context is: /concept/title/

I want to return any concept title element that contains any open parenthesis, with any text, and a close parenthesis.  I want it to locate (ANT) or any other text inside ( ).

I was successful with `/context/title/text(), "("`

But it only located and highlighted (  not (ANT)

How can I modify the xpath 2.0 to locate any concept title element that contains an acronym presented within parenthesis.

Comment: Your example is neither valid XML nor did you given any specific XPath. Please give the concrete data and XPath, your current question makes it very difficult to guess which data you have and what you already tried and want to achieve.

Comment: Do you use xslt or xpaht only? And should it be xpath-1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: XML is:  

<concept><title>Another Neat Tool (ANT)</title></concept>

xpath 2.0 please, I tried: /concept/title/text(), "("

This returned just the beginning parenthesis (  I want it to return (ANT)

Comment: Do you guarantee every `title` that has an opening `"("`, will also have a closing `")"`?

Comment: Yes if the title contains an acronym the acronym is always contained within parenthesis.  For example:

<concept><title>Automated Teller Machine (ATM)</title></concept>
<concept><title>Central Standard Time (CST)</title></concept>

the xpath would return both of the concept elements and highlight both (ATM) and (CST)

I would not want the xpath expression to return any <concept><title> that do not contain an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression (you may need to adapt it to include your root node):

```
/concept/title[contains(text(),"(") AND contains(text(),")")]/substring-before(substring-after(text(),"("),")")
```

[Online test code here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EAutomated%20Teller%20Machine%20%28ATM%29%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E%0D%0A%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3ECentral%20Standard%20Time%20%28CST%29%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E%0D%0A%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOPEN%20AND%20CLOSE%20%28ABC%29%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E%0D%0A%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3ECLOSE%20ONLY%20DEF%29%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E%0D%0A%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOPEN%20ONLY%20%28GHI%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E%0D%0A%3Cconcept%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOPEN%20AND%20CLOSE%20%28TEST%29%3C/title%3E%0D%0A%3C/concept%3E&extract=/concept/title%5Bcontains%28text%28%29,%22%28%22%29%20AND%20contains%28text%28%29,%22%29%22%29%5D/substring-before%28substring-after%28text%28%29,%22%28%22%29,%22%29%22%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&extract-kind=xpath&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto).

From this:

```xml
<concept>
  <title>Automated Teller Machine (ATM)</title>
</concept>
<concept>
  <title>Central Standard Time (CST)</title>
</concept>
<concept>
  <title>OPEN AND CLOSE (ABC)</title>
</concept>
<concept>
  <title>CLOSE ONLY DEF)</title>
</concept>
<concept>
  <title>OPEN ONLY (GHI</title>
</concept>
<concept>
  <title>OPEN AND CLOSE (TEST)</title>
</concept>
```

It returns this:

```
ATM
CST
ABC
TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression

```
/concept/title[matches(., '\([A-Z]{2,}\)')]
```

will return a sequence of all /concept/title elements that contain an acronym, defined as two or more capital letters in parentheses.

If you want to return the acronym letters themselves, you can use

```
/concept/title[matches(., '\([A-Z]{2,}\)')]/
   replace(., '^.*\(([A-Z]{2,})\).*$', '$1')
```